# IIS sharing cookies between ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, forms-authentication

We have a suite of applications that all sit under a website in IIS (Server 2012). We intended to migrate all these applications to .NET Core 2.1 but we have run out of time and now I need to look at the prospect of getting the older applications authenticated to the .NET Core portal. 
The older web sites use Forms Authentication and I hoped that I could make the .NET Core portal create a Forms Authentication Cookie when logged in to and the older applications would be none the wiser

Ive found this promising github -

https://github.com/synercoder/FormsAuthentication

and this works perfect locally

However when I put the application on IIS on the server it doesn't work - The older applications come up with the login screen. By using fiddler it appears the .NET Core and old applications do not "share" all their cookies. The session cookie is shared and the .NET Core application gets all the older application cookies but the older applications do not get the .NET Core cookies of which the Forms Authentication Cookie is one. Again they happily can share each others cookies locally (IISExpress)

Im getting to the end of my tether does anybody have any ideas why the old applications do not see the .NET Core cookies in IIS on the server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, you need to use same Application Pool on both .NET Core and old applications.

Don't worry about .NET CLR Version(No Managed Code) for .NET Core application. It will work fine with v4.